# Filter after input PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm quite new in PHP and I am working on two pages.
My table in db would be like:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_module
(
    module_id int,
    module_name varchar(255)
);
INSERT INTO tbl_module
    (module_id, module_name) 
VALUES 
    (1,"001-erty"),
    (2,"002-yuio"),
    (3,"001-vbnm"),
    (4,"003-hjkl"),
    (5,"001-qwer"),
    (6,"001-dfgh");
```

First Page only looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="module_name">
<input type="submit" name="btn_save" value="Save">
<?php 

    if (!empty(isset($_POST["btn_save"])))
    {

      $project_type = $_POST["project_type"];
      mysql_query ("INSERT INTO tbl_modules(module_name) VALUES('$module_name')"); 

  ?>
```

Once I click the button, it will take me to the second page which I wanted to be in this kind of output:

```
=============
HISTORY
-------------
001-erty
001-vbnm
001-qwer
001-dfgh

=============
RECENT INPUT
-------------
001-asdf
```

Let's assume that our recent input was '001-asdf'. In HISTORY, it only shows the modules that match the recent one. As you can see in 'tbl_modules', the modules not starting with '001-...' did not appear in HISTORY.

My problem is that I couldn't get the right query for it to appear like that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @PraveenKumar :sorry sorry. quite new here. I just wanted my output to display those identical to my previous inputs to the second page. There are so many questions I had in mind and I don't know exactly what to ask after all those codes i have tried. Sorry

Comment: It looks good now.

Comment: Still not exactly clear what you want ... do you want to limit the amount of results you get back from that select statement?

Comment: Then you could use $query=mysql_query("SELECT project_name FROM tbl_history_projects ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10.") or something like this ... If you have an auto-increment field.

Comment: Edited. Hope you would understand this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply split your recent input with PHP explode function

```
$module_fname = explode('-',$module_name)[0];
```

and then

```
SELECT module_name FROM [tbl_module] WHERE module_name LIKE $module_fname.'%'
```

Comment: This helps. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, since I cannot comment, I could not clarify what you were expecting. However, I will answer to my understanding.

Your table tbl_module has no auto increment field. 
If it were included, there can be two queries which we can use for your scenario.

"SELECT project_name FROM tbl_module ORDER BY module_id LIMIT 10" . Here 10 denoting the number of entries you want to show in the history.

As for the last one "Recent Entries" is something similar except we take the ORDER BY module_id DESC to get the most recent entries.

Hope this would help.

Edit: -  My first one has a slight mistake, here is the updated one:-

"SELECT project_name FROM tbl_module ORDER BY module_id,project_name LIMIT 10"

Comment: Adniwhack .Thanks for that but I think you misunderstood my problem. What I only want is to find those that match my recent input based on the left characters (e.g '001-').